# Error converting a string to a date and/or time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column named "Period". In this column, year and month are entered consecutively. For example, in "201803", 2018 represents the year and 03 represents March. I want to create a date column in the format of "01.03.2018" using this column. Day should be only 01.

When I use the following code,

```
CONCAT(RIGHT('00' + CAST(RIGHT([Period], 2) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2), '-01-', CAST(Left([Period], 4) AS VARCHAR(4)))
```

it works, but I see the date in the format of "03.01.2018", meaning the day and month are swapped.

However, when I enter the code in the following way;

```
'01.' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(RIGHT(  RIGHT([Period], 2) , 2) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + '.' + CAST(LEFT( LEFT([Period], 4) , 4) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

I receive the following error.

> Error converting a string to a date and/or time.

How can I solve this issue in T-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yyyyMMdd` is already an unambiguous date format for *all* date and time data types in SQL Server, so just add `'01'` to the end of the string. As, however, storing "date" values in a non-date and time data type tends to also result in bad data (like `202713`) then you'll likely want to use `TRY_CONVERT` too:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date,CONCAT(Period,'01'))
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: It's best to think simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the below to get the output like "01.03.2018":

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, TRY_CONVERT(DATE,CONCAT([Period],'01')), 104)
```